# unable to resolve Datagrid combobox column binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that is bound to TeamMembers. In the code behind constructor:

```
 public SetupView(SetupViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = model;
        this.model = model;
        ResourceGrid.ItemsSource = model.teamMembers;
        ResourceGrid.DataContext = model;
    }
```

My ViewModel :

```
public class SetUpViewModel {
Tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

}
```

In my XAML , My ResourceGrid is a Data grid that has one ComboBoxColumn :

```
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Task" Width="115"  ItemsSource="{Binding 
Tasks}"  ">
```

the Tasks in the binding refers to the Tasks Collection I declared in my view model. However when I run this it doesn work.

But if I do this where I add combo to Template column and then add items source of combobox to tasks on load combo , it works :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Task" Width="115">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Loaded="LoadATaskEventHandler"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>



private void LoadATaskEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;


        comboBox.ItemsSource=model.Tasks;

    }
```

I dotn want to add combobox to template when datagrid supports comobocolumn. Please advise on this.

And what difference in performance and what is the best solution out of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the ComboBox has a different `DataContext` than the rest of your view.  Try:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType = DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.Tasks}"
```

I think the difference in performance between the approaches is probably negligable, but doing it directly through bindings is better to avoid tight coupling.

Comment: thanks !! before I accept . Could you just explain which approach has tighter coupling ? the one with Combobox in DataTemplate ?

Comment: No problem.  Generally speaking, (this case included), using events in codebehind is tighter coupling than data-binding.

Comment: Hi, I tried this out today and it still didn't work for me .  it cant resolve Path=DataContext.Tasks    (underlined is Tasks) . I provided the datacontext of my grid in the code behing as ResourceGrid.DataContext = model; And my model has the Observable collection Tasks :(

Comment: First, make sure that the LoadATaskEventHandler event handler is no longer doing anything, since that could interfere with the Binding.  Also, get rid of `ResourceGrid.ItemsSource = model.teamMembers;` in the view's constructor, since that could be interfering with the binding.

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems that your grid is not bound to a SetupViewModel